# How to pipe all bash terminal output through command

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe, cowsay

I would like to be able to pipe all bash terminal commands through a certain command (for no good reason other than to play a prank on someone). I just want to pipe the stdout of any executed command into a predetermined program without doing anything special.

For example:
If that predetermined program was `cowsay`

```
echo "Hello World"
```

should output

```
 _____________
< Hello World >
 -------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

How can I achieve this? (Some of the fun programs I'd like to use to play pranks on others include `rev`, `cowsay`, and `lolcat`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
exec > >(COMMAND)
```

Where `COMMAND` is `rev`, `lolcat` or other. This won't work with `cowsay`.

E.g.

```
bash-4.3$ exec > >(rev)
bash-4.3$ echo hello
olleh
```

Explanation:

- `exec` normally replaces the current shell with another process, but if you just give it a redirection like in this case, the redirection will take place for the current shell.
- `>` redirect stdout
- `>(COMMAND)` input into `COMMAND`

Note that if you have a `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you should direct it to stderr to avoid the redirected stdout.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, two questions: 1. It works great for tools like lolcat or rev which operate on a line by line basis. But for cowsay, it waits until I press ctrl-d, then outputs everything. How can we make it add an EOF to each command, and spawn a new cowsay each time?

Comment: @vikarjramun Yeah, I'm having the same problem. Must be a buffering thing. I'm researching it now

Comment: @wjandrea Perhaps the [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) command from `expect` could help.

Comment: @wjandrea my first thought was `xargs cowsay` but that didn't work. Maybe `xargs bash -c "echo {} | cowsay"`? I'll try that and see.

Comment: @PerlDuck I couldn't get it to work. I tried it with and without the `-p` flag.

Comment: The closest I've come yet is using `exec > >(while read line; do cowsay <<<"$line"; done)` or `exec > >(xargs -l cowsay)`, but it prints after the next prompt has already come up.

Comment: I don't know about the `-p` flag but it was just a guess anyway. Maybe the bash itself needs to be run via `unbuffer` but I wouldn't dare that. Perhaps we should accept that we cannot tame the cow.

Comment: Well, if the only problem left is the prompt coming up to early, let's just delay the prompt... `PS1="\$(sleep 1)$PS1"` ;-) Tested it, works fine with `exec > >(xargs -l cowsay)`

Comment: @LienhartWoitok I tried that too, but with a command that produces a lot of output lines, like `ls`, it doesn't work.